# having error implementing Viterbi algorithm in python

Tags: python, algorithm, machine-learning, data-science

I am new to data science and trying to run Viterbi code from github but when i am passing my parameters to the function it is showing error
only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

My function of Viterbi algorithm

```
def Viterbi(pi, a, b, obs):
    nStates = np.shape(b)[0]
    T = np.shape(obs)[0]
    path = np.zeros(T)
    delta = np.zeros((nStates, T))
    phi = np.zeros((nStates, T))
    delta[:, 0] = pi * b[:, obs[0]]
    phi[:, 0] = 0
    for t in range(1,T):
        for s in range(nStates):
            delta[s, t] = np.max(delta[:, t-1] * a[:, s]) * b[s, obs[t]]
            phi[s, t] = np.argmax(delta[:, t-1] * a[:, s])
   path[T-1] = np.argmax(delta[:,T-1])
   for t in range(T-2, -1, -1):
       path[t] = phi[path[t+1], t+1]
   return path, delta, phi
```

I am passing function parameters as numpy.ndarray.
Can anyone suggest what is this error and how to solve this

Error Screenshot
[image: Scrrenshot of the error]

Attaching the link from where i got the code
[code link](https://github.com/alexsosn/MarslandMLAlgo/blob/master/Ch16/HMM.py)

Comment: Can you add the parameters you're having an error with?

Comment: The algorithm looks fine. Seems like the data you are passing does not ft the function's logic. Did you check the documentation of that code?

Comment: You are passing `path[t+1]` as row selecting index to `phi`. Hence the error, can you check the shape of `path[t+1]`? Is it one dimensional?